# Pulseaudio: clear preferences saved by plugin module-stream-restore

Tags: pulseaudio

I am trying to find a way for PulseAudio to clear all the saved associations between input/output streams and sources/sinks, which get saved by the plugin module-stream-restore.I want to do this to only happen at login.

As far as I could find, the easiest way would be to load the plugin module-stream-restore with **restore_device=false**, and it does work. However, it creates a major inconvenient if one wants to change a stream's sink to one different than the default, especially if that stream gets interrupted and recreated often (such as with browser videos, for example), because it causes the stream to lose the setting and fallback to the default sink, which is annoying. Thus, I am looking for a way, if possible, to manually clear these saved associations (at my convenience).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On my system (non-standard Pulseaudio usage), the Pulseaudio database files are in `$HOME/.pulse/`. The file ending in `stream-volumes.tdb` contains the associations. The file format used is the *trivial database*, you can dump it with `tdbdump` (part of Samba). I suppose removing it should clear the associations.

Pulseaudio also supports the `gdbm` (GNU Database Manager) format. Moreover, I don't know where it puts those files if it's started by the system. Maybe searching for (or `locate`ing) `stream-volumes` can help.

Edit: fixed typo

Comment: The only minor remark I'd have is that on openSuse it's $HOME/.config/pulse. However, your solution worked, thanks.